# MATLAB: How to re-label a matrix based on another matrix?

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, label, segment

Say I have matrix A:

```
A = [1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3; 
     1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3; 
     1 1 1 2 2 4 4 5; 
     2 2 2 2 2 5 5 5]
```

and matrix B with the same labels, just in different positions and not always with the same elements in each cluster:

```
B = [3 3 3 3 5 1 1 1:
     3 3 3 3 5 1 1 1;
     3 3 3 3 5 2 2 4:
     5 5 5 5 5 4 4 4]
```

and I want matrix C to look like this

```
C = [1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3;
     1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3;
     1 1 1 1 2 4 4 5;
     2 2 2 2 2 5 5 5]
```

Basically, I want the clusters in B that have a similar position to A to also have the same label as A, even if the clusters in B don't have the same exact amount of elements as the clusters in A. This is just a basic example because what I'm really working on are two images that have different labellings.

[example of the image I'm working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h07uX.jpg)

Comment: if they dont have the same elements, can you describe how to match them? How do you find one in another?

Comment: @AnderBiguri That's where I'm facing difficulty. Because if you look at the image I attached, not all the clusters in the right figure look exactly the same as those in the left figure (thus, different number of elements). So I don't know how to relabel them so that the clusters in the 2nd have the same values as those of the 1st figure.

Comment: So, for each label in B, you want to find the most frequent value in A, then apply the mapping to re-number B.

Comment: I’m thinking `splitapply(@mode,A(:),B(:))` will give you the mapping, but I can’t try it out right now.